# ISO-88591 charset / text-encoding of jQuery UI / mobile possible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Searched the web, but failed to find a definite explanation. Several people reported problems and some claimed that UTF-8 is required. Therefore:

- My I use **jQuery UI / mobile with any charset**?
- May I especially use **ISO-88591**?
- Or does jQuery UI / mobile **require UTF-8**?

Certainly, the site uses this meta-tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Certain browser running on certain operation systems fail to display diacritical characters correct, name these characters ö ä ü Ö Ä Ü ß:

**Mac OS X**

- **OK** : Safari, Firefox, Chrome

**Windows XP**

- **OK** : Chrome [26.0.*]
- **PARTIAL** : Firefox [18.0.1], IE [8.*]

In case of **PARTIAL**, diacriticals sometimes appear fine, sometimes appear like � or such.

As far as I figured out, if jQuery reloads a 'partial', diacriticals break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a thread about this topic on the jQuery UI forum, check the encoding of the jquery-ui.min.js. Try editing jquery-ui.min.js directly to use charset iso-8859-1 and it should work. (ref. https://forum.jquery.com/topic/weird-characters-showing-up-in-datepicker)